# Convert supplementary characters to Chinese characters

Tags: c#

I have a string of supplementary characters:

```
Ë¤Èí¹Ä
```

That I need to convert to Chinese Characters. Using notepad++ I am able to do this by setting encoding to ANSI, paste the above supplementary characters, then change encoding to Simplified Chinese (GB2312) to get the following correct answer:

```
摔软鼓
```

Is there a way to convert supplementary characters to Chinese Characters using c#?
How Can I mimic that function from notepad++ using c#?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "supplementary characters" here - the values you've pasted are within the BMP.  I would ignore the idea of *characters* here to start with - what *binary data* are you loading in the first place, and how are you loading it? The problem is probably there.

Comment: I just want to know how to mimic the function of notepad++, that I did above, in c#.

Comment: That's a bad idea. It's *very* possible that that approach will lose data in many cases. You should instead be trying to work out why you've got the wrong text to start with, and fix that... which means going back to the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using notepad++ I am able to do this by setting encoding to ANSI, paste the above supplementary characters, then change encoding to Simplified Chinese (GB2312)

This is what you want to do:

```
var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes("Ë¤Èí¹Ä");
var text = Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312").GetString(bytes); // 摔软鼓
```

Comment: Except that may well lose data, as I mentioned before. The OP really, really should look at loading the data properly to start with.